# PostGIS make buffer on LINESTRING Z to have a POLYGON Z

Tags: postgresql, geometry, postgis

I have several `LINESTRING Z` geometies in PostgreSQL and they look like
`LINESTRING Z (1 2 1,1 1 4)`

I want to make a buffer around this linestring so that i can have a `POLYGON Z geometry` for further export to dxf.

I tried this

```sql
select st_astext(st_buffer('LINESTRING Z (1 2 1,1 1 4)'::geometry, 2)) as geom;
```

and it gives me

`POLYGON((3 1,2.96157056080646 0.609819355967741,2.84775906502257 0.23463313526
9818,2.66293922460509 -0.111140466039206,2.41421356237309 -0.414213562373096,2.
1111404660392 -0.662939224605091,1.76536686473018 -0.847759065022574,1.39018064
403226 -0.961570560806461,1 -1,0.609819355967745 -0.961570560806461,0.234633135
269822 -0.847759065022574,-0.111140466039202 -0.662939224605092,-0.414213562373
094 -0.414213562373096,-0.662939224605089 -0.111140466039207,-0.847759065022572
 0.234633135269818,-0.96157056080646 0.609819355967739,-1 1,-1 2,-0.96157056080
646 2.39018064403226,-0.847759065022572 2.76536686473018,-0.662939224605089 3.1
1114046603921,-0.414213562373094 3.4142135623731,-0.111140466039203 3.662939224
60509,0.234633135269821 3.84775906502257,0.609819355967744 3.96157056080646,1 4
,1.39018064403226 3.96157056080646,1.76536686473018 3.84775906502257,2.11114046
60392 3.66293922460509,2.41421356237309 3.4142135623731,2.66293922460509 3.1111
4046603921,2.84775906502257 2.76536686473018,2.96157056080646 2.39018064403226,
3 2,3 1)) (1 row)`

which is in `2D POLYGON` not `POLYGON Z`

How can I make it 3D?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure what you want to achieve, but did you take a look at [`ST_Force3D`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Force_3D.html)?

```sql
SELECT 
  ST_AsText(
    ST_Force3D(
      ST_Buffer('LINESTRING Z (1 2 1,1 1 4)'::GEOMETRY, 2)));
```

It will return a `POLYGON Z` geometry:

```
 POLYGON Z ((3 1 0,2.96157056080646 0.609819355967741 0,2.84775906502257 0.234633135269818 0,2.66293922460509 -0.111140466039206 0,2.41421356237309 -0.414213562373096 0,2.1111404660392 -0.662939224605091 0,1.76536686473018 -0.847759065022574 0,1.39018064403226 -0.961570560806461 0,1 -1 0,0.609819355967745 -0.961570560806461 0,0.234633135269822 -0.847759065022574 0,-0.111140466039202 -0.662939224605092 0,-0.414213562373094 -0.414213562373096 0,-0.662939224605089 -0.111140466039207 0,-0.847759065022572 0.234633135269818 0,-0.96157056080646 0.609819355967739 0,-1 1 0,-1 2 0,-0.96157056080646 2.39018064403226 0,-0.847759065022572 2.76536686473018 0,-0.662939224605089 3.11114046603921 0,-0.414213562373094 3.4142135623731 0,-0.111140466039203 3.66293922460509 0,0.234633135269821 3.84775906502257 0,0.609819355967744 3.96157056080646 0,1 4 0,1.39018064403226 3.96157056080646 0,1.76536686473018 3.84775906502257 0,2.1111404660392 3.66293922460509 0,2.41421356237309 3.4142135623731 0,2.66293922460509 3.11114046603921 0,2.84775906502257 2.76536686473018 0,2.96157056080646 2.39018064403226 0,3 2 0,3 1 0))
```

The function [`ST_Buffer`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Buffer.html) discards the Z dimension, as stated in the documentation:

> ... This function ignores the third dimension (z) and will always give a
>   2-d buffer even when presented with a 3d-geometry.

**EDIT:**

This query sort of creates a buffer with the average Z value of a given `LINESTRING Z`.

```
WITH j AS (
SELECT 
  ST_DumpPoints(
    ST_Buffer('LINESTRING Z (1 2 1,1 1 4)'::GEOMETRY, 2)
  ) AS pt,
  (SELECT AVG(z) AS avg_z 
  FROM (SELECT ST_Z((ST_DumpPoints('LINESTRING Z (1 2 1,1 1 4)'::GEOMETRY)).geom) AS z) AS z) AS lsz
)
SELECT ST_AsText(
  ST_MakePolygon(ST_MakeLine(ST_MakePoint(ST_X((pt).geom),ST_Y((pt).geom),lsz))))
FROM j
GROUP BY lsz;

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
POLYGON Z ((3 1 2.5,2.96157056080646 0.609819355967741 2.5,2.84775906502257 0.234633135269818 2.5,2.66293922460509 -0.111140466039206 2.5,2.41421356237309 -0.414213562373096 2.5,2.1111404660392 -0.662939224605091 2.5,1.76536686473018 -0.847759065022574 2.5,1.39018064403226 -0.961570560806461 2.5,1 -1 2.5,0.609819355967745 -0.961570560806461 2.5,0.234633135269822 -0.847759065022574 2.5,-0.111140466039202 -0.662939224605092 2.5,-0.414213562373094 -0.414213562373096 2.5,-0.662939224605089 -0.111140466039207 2.5,-0.847759065022572 0.234633135269818 2.5,-0.96157056080646 0.609819355967739 2.5,-1 1 2.5,-1 2 2.5,-0.96157056080646 2.39018064403226 2.5,-0.847759065022572 2.76536686473018 2.5,-0.662939224605089 3.11114046603921 2.5,-0.414213562373094 3.4142135623731 2.5,-0.111140466039203 3.66293922460509 2.5,0.234633135269821 3.84775906502257 2.5,0.609819355967744 3.96157056080646 2.5,1 4 2.5,1.39018064403226 3.96157056080646 2.5,1.76536686473018 3.84775906502257 2.5,2.1111404660392 3.66293922460509 2.5,2.41421356237309 3.4142135623731 2.5,2.66293922460509 3.11114046603921 2.5,2.84775906502257 2.76536686473018 2.5,2.96157056080646 2.39018064403226 2.5,3 2 2.5,3 1 2.5))
(1 row)
```

Comment: `ST_Force3D` forces `POLYGON` to `POLYGON Z` by giving 0 z-value to all vertices so it ends up a 2D geometry in 3D world. What I wanted was a 3D geometry with actualy Z value

Comment: @eth4io I see. I just added a new query that creates a polygon z from a buffer created out of a linestring z with the average z value, since the linestring has multiple Z values. If it works for you I can add a few more comments to the answer.

Comment: Thanks! This looks really close to what I need but to my understanding all points are still at one vertical level (z = 4) so it's technically still a plane not a 3D buffer. Is it possible to grant different z value to those vertices? My thought was, in order to construct a 3D buffer (should be a cylinder), we need some points with z value = 0 and some points with z value = 4 (approximate number as the sample linestring is not perfectly vertical.

Comment: I guess it is possible. You'd just need to iterate over these vertices (from the dump function) and change the Z value accordingly, and then create the polygon. But based on which criteria would some vertices have different values, e.g. 0?

Comment: Let's use a even simpler example LINESTRING Z (1 1 1,1 1 4), a vertical line from (1, 1, 1) to (1, 1, 4). if we make a 3D buffer for this LINESTRING Z it should like a vertical cylinder so the points to construct this 3D buffer would be like (1 0 1, 1-sqrt(2)/2 1-sqrt(2)/2 1, 0 1 1, 1-sqrt(2)/2 1+sqrt(2)/2 1......, 1 0 4, 1-sqrt(2)/2 1-sqrt(2)/2 4, 0 1 4, 1-sqrt(2)/2 1+sqrt(2)/2 4, ....)

Comment: Strange. So I erroneously assumed the `POLYGON Z` I created with my last query would already return this cylinder - polygon/buffer with the Z value of 2.5 in all vertices. I do not have a 3d wkt viewer, so I cannot see where it might be failing :)

Comment: it might be right! Sorry i don't have my env available atm but will let you know as soon as i have chance.

Comment: All right. If the average Z value does not work for you, just change the CTE where the function `avg()` is used, e.g. with `max()`. In case you indeed need a different Z value for each node of the polygon, you can change it in the `ST_MakePoint(x,y,z)` function by means of changing the variable `lsz` to the value you want. If it works, it would be nice if you could add a screenshot of the cylinder, so that other users can profit form our discussion. Good luck!

Comment: hey @eth4io which viewer you use for 3D geometries? I just stumbled into this requirement at university I am wondering which tool you're using :)

Comment: I export geometry from PostgreSQL to dxf format, then view them in [Blender](https://www.blender.org/) with a dxf import plugin

Comment: I just tested your edited query. It gives me a polygon z but after exporting to dxf i can't load it into blender.

Comment: code i used
```bash
ogr2ogr -f "DXF" test_cylinder.dxf PG:"host='127.0.0.1' dbname='dbname' user='user' password='password'" -sql "WITH j AS ( \
SELECT ST_DumpPoints( \
    ST_Buffer('LINESTRING Z (1 2 1,1 1 4)'::GEOMETRY, 2) \
  ) AS pt, \
  (SELECT AVG(z) AS avg_z  \
  FROM (SELECT ST_Z((ST_DumpPoints('LINESTRING Z (1 2 1,1 1 4)'::GEOMETRY)).geom) AS z) AS z) AS lsz \
) \
SELECT ST_MakePolygon(ST_MakeLine(ST_MakePoint(ST_X((pt).geom),ST_Y((pt).geom),lsz))) \
FROM j \
GROUP BY lsz"
```